# Code explanation in Java

Tags: java, generics

this morning I came across this code, and I have absolutely no idea what that means. Can anyone explain me what do these `<T>` represent? For example:

```
public class MyClass<T>
...

some bits of code then 

private Something<T> so;

private OtherThing<T> to;

private Class<T> c;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have bumped into "generics". They are explained very nicely in this [guide](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

In short, they allow you to specify what type that a storage-class, such as a `List` or `Set` contains. If you write `Set<String>`, you have stated that this set must only contain `String`s, and will get a compilation error if you try to put something else in there:

```
Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<String>();
stringSet.add("hello"); //ok.
stringSet.add(3);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^ //does not compile
```

Furthermore, another useful example of what generics can do is that they allow you to more closely specify an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstClass<T extends Variable> {
```

In this way, the extending classes does not have to extend `Variable`, but they need to extend a class that extends `Variable`.

Accordingly, a method that handles an `AbstClass` can be defined like this:

```
public void doThing(AbstClass<?> abstExtension) {
```

where `?` is a wildcard that means "all classes that extend `AbstClass` with some `Variable`".

Comment: @Lars Andren Ok I think I got the explanation, why would anyone use generics in class name, I mean is there an application to it by using it or not using it?

Comment: You can't really add generics to a class name, but you can add generics to the class header (definition). The advantages of using it are fewer casts and improved readability among others; http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#Topic1

Answer (score 5):

What you see here is something called Generics. They were introduced to Java in release 1.5.

You can read about them [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you're writing a List or Array class. This class must be able to hold elements of an unknown type. How do you do that?

[Generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/) answers this question. Those `<T>` you're seeing can be read as `some type`. With generics you can write `class MyList<T> { ... }`, which in this context means `a list that holds some type`.

As an usage example, declare a list to store integers, `MyList<Integer> listOfInts`, or strings, `MyList<String> listOfStrings`, or one class you've written yourself `MyList<MyClass> listOfMyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is [Java generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/), which allows classes and methods to be parameterized by other classes. This is especially useful when creating container classes, since it saves you having to create separate classes for "a list of integers", "a list of strings", etc. Instead, you can have a single "list of some type T, where T is a variable" and then you can instantiate the list for some specific type T. Note that Java generics is not quite the same as template types in C++; Java generics actually use the same class definition but add implicit casting (generated by the compiler) and add additional type-checking. However, the different instantiations actually make use of the same exact type (this is known as erasure), where the parameterized types are replaced with Object. You can read more about this at the link.

Answer (score 0):

Since noone has mentioned it yet, there is a very comprehensive guide/FAQ/tutorial on generics which can be found on [Angelika Langer's site](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Comment: Actually, that was already linked to from Lars Andren's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719776/code-explanation-in-java/2719918#2719918